# Launchscreen.storyboard Loaclization not working

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have the following Problem. I have an app with the Base Language which is English and Localization for German.

The Launchscreen.storyboard which I use contains 3 images (1 background image and 2 logos). One of the logo changed in the German storyboard into a other Logo. The Localization is created as Interface Builder Storyboard.

My Problem is, if I Build the App on a Device which has settings German, The Launchscreen is English. Also after restarting and deleting app, Derived Data and Clean everything didn't solve the Problem.

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and iOS 10.3.3 Building Devices are iPhone 5s, 6+, 6S and 6S+ on no device will it work.

Maybe someone had the same issue and solved this problem?

Comment: No luck :P https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/. "Avoid including text on your launch screen. Because launch screens are static, any displayed text won’t be localized.

" This storyboard can't internalization since they are created a static image on the moment they compile.

Comment: I don't use text so the first sentence is not important for me. And why should they have localizable Storyboards when they will not compile it? make no sense or?